# Get Supplier name where all items supplied are above average

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables,

```
SUPPLIERS(
    SUPPCODE,
    SUPPNAME,
    STREET,
    TOWN,
    COUNTRY,
    POSTCODE,
    TELNO,
    FAXNO)

STOCKS(
    STOCKNO,
    STORECODE,
    DESCRIPTION,
    QUANTITY,
    UNITS,
    REORDER,
    PRICE,
    SUPPCODE)
```

I want to find the name of the suppliers where the price of all the items they supply is greater than the average for the price of all items in the table.

I know I can find all items above average using

```
SELECT  S1.SuppCode, S1.SuppName, S1.PostCode
FROM    Suppliers S1, Stocks S2
WHERE   Price > (
    SELECT  AVG(Price)
    FROM    Stocks
    )
AND S1.SuppCode = S2.SuppCode;
```

But I'm not sure how to make sure every item for a supplier is greater than the average.

The average is

```
AVG(PRICE)                                                                      
----------                                                                      
5.14411765
```

And the table looks like this

```
SQL> select suppcode, price
  2  from stocks
  3  order by suppcode
  4  ;

SUPPCO      PRICE                                                               
------ ----------                                                               
S1           2.85                                                               
S1           2.85                                                               
S1           2.14                                                               
S1            .49                                                               
S1            .98                                                               
S1           1.59                                                               
S1           1.84                                                               
S1           1.35                                                               
S2           5.15                                                               
S2           2.98                                                               
S2          11.38                                                               

SUPPCO      PRICE                                                               
------ ----------                                                               
S2          12.85                                                               
S3           2.57                                                               
S3           4.95                                                               
S3           1.89                                                               
S3           4.11                                                               
S3           8.58                                                               
S3           1.97                                                               
S3            .81                                                               
S3           6.19                                                               
S3           3.65                                                               
S4           4.83                                                               

SUPPCO      PRICE                                                               
------ ----------                                                               
S4           2.42                                                               
S4            .22                                                               
S4            .45                                                               
S4            .47                                                               
S4            .42                                                               
S4           2.15                                                               
S4           3.48                                                               
S5           7.99                                                               
S5           7.85                                                               
S5           6.47                                                               
S6          23.99                                                               

SUPPCO      PRICE                                                               
------ ----------                                                               
S6          32.99
```

So given this I want to get S5 and S6.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, he wants to know the name of the supplier who only sells items above the average price

Comment: Just as an advice for next time, whenever you have an SQL question, please provide an SQLFiddle with the data. Just go to http://sqlfiddle.com/ and create a table with your data. Then post the link in the question. This will help us, who try to answer your question, to show you on YOUR data how the queries work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0fb80/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE SUPPLIERS(
    SUPPCODE NUMBER(5,0) PRIMARY KEY,
    SUPPNAME VARCHAR2(20),
    STREET   VARCHAR2(20),
    TOWN     VARCHAR2(20),
    COUNTRY  VARCHAR2(20),
    POSTCODE VARCHAR2(20),
    TELNO    NUMBER(11,0),
    FAXNO    NUMBER(11,0)
);

CREATE TABLE STOCKS(
    STOCKNO     NUMBER(5,0) PRIMARY KEY,
    STORECODE   VARCHAR2(20),
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(20),
    QUANTITY    NUMBER(5,0),
    UNITS       NUMBER(5,0),
    REORDER     NUMBER(5,0),
    PRICE       NUMBER(12,2),
    SUPPCODE    NUMBER(5,0),
    FOREIGN KEY ( SUPPCODE ) REFERENCES SUPPLIERS ( SUPPCODE )
);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SUPPCODE
FROM   SUPPLIERS s
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   STOCKS k
                   WHERE  s.SUPPCODE = k.SUPPCODE
                   AND    price <= (SELECT AVG( price ) AS avg_price FROM STOCKS)
                  )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0fb80/1/0)**: